# Pattern Matching Using Regular Expressions in Python

Tags: python

I hope you guys are doing well. I have a question. I have this string of characters "First, after preprocessing, citation data are carefully analysed for the analysis tasks (T1, T2, T3, T4) to establish a new ranking model."
How to match 3 or 4 words before and after the bracket (T1,T2,T3,T4).

Comment: Can you give an example of your string and exactly what should be matched? Also look at https://regex101.com/ so you can try some variants of regex.

Comment: 'First, after preprocessing, citation data are carefully analysed for the analysis tasks (T1, T2, T3, T4) to establish a new ranking model based on citation context.'     This is the example string and i want to match just 3 words before or after bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the any word character of regex `\w`:

```
import re

line =  'First, after preprocessing, citation data are carefully analysed for the analysis tasks (T1, T2, T3, T4) to establish a new ranking model based on citation context.' 

reg = r'(\w+\s){3}\('
re.compile(reg).search(line).group()[:-1]
>>> 'the analysis tasks '
```

It search for the combination of words and spaces three times (hence the three) and at the end there as to be a bracket `\(`. The slicing at the end is to subtract the bracket, which was also found, but you were not interested in the bracket but only in the three words. One can also slice the last two characters since the last character was a space.

When there is a comma in front of the brackets (which is a non-word character) you can rewrite your line to find words with word boundary's:

```
reg = r'(\w+\W+){3}\('
```

Answer (score 0):

I think OP wants to get a certain number of "words" before or after this block (.*).

```
import re
string = "First, after preprocessing, citation data are carefully analysed for the analysis tasks (T1, T2, T3, T4) to establish a new ranking model."
before, after = [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'\(.*\)', string)]
print(before)
print(after)
```

Output

```
First, after preprocessing, citation data are carefully analysed for the analysis tasks
to establish a new ranking model.
```

---

```
print(before.split(' ')[-3:])
print(after.split(' ')[:3])
```

Output

```
['the', 'analysis', 'tasks']
['to', 'establish', 'a']
```

Comment: Thanks bro. This is gonna be very helpful. <3